# Access td dynamically based on the table cell button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I understand this question might be the same. I have googled, unfortunately I might have have missed something similar. I apologies for the same.

I have created a dynamic table in JavaScript based on some JSON response and updated the table accordingly. Now J have a submit button which posts currently selected raw data as an ajax call. In the table,there is a hidden element in one cell of each row and there is one Apply button per row.

So, I want to fetch the hidden element data when I press the button.

Following are the codes :

**JS **

```
var cell0;var cell1;var cell2;var cell3;var cell4;var cell5;
var cell6;var cell7;var cell8;
var cell9;
var jobID;$(document).ready(function(){
$('#ajax-button').click(function() {
    var formData=$("#careers").serialize();
    console.log("This is the skills : "+formData);
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "currentopening",
            //data : "skills="+skills,
            data:formData,
            dataType : "json",
            async: true,
            success : function(response) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(response);

                console.log("length of json response : "+obj.length)
                if(obj.length>0){
                //for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) 
                //{
                    console.log("the characteristics : "+obj[0].title);
                    addRow(obj);
                //}
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("dynamictable").innerHTML="No jobs found!";
                }
            }
        });
    });    
});function addRow(obj) {

var table_1 = document.getElementById("dynamictable");

for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){

var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
btn.appendChild(t);
btn.id="apply-button";

var input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute("id",obj[i].jobID);
input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
input.setAttribute("name", "jobID");
input.setAttribute("value", obj[i].jobID);

var rowCount = table_1.getElementsByTagName("tr").length;

var row1 = table_1.insertRow(rowCount);
row1.id="x";

 cell0=row1.insertCell(0);
 cell1=row1.insertCell(1);
 cell2=row1.insertCell(2);
 cell3=row1.insertCell(3);
 cell4=row1.insertCell(4);
 cell5=row1.insertCell(5);
 cell6=row1.insertCell(6);
 cell7=row1.insertCell(7);
 cell8=row1.insertCell(8);
 cell9=row1.insertCell(9);

cell0.headers="title"; cell1.headers="qualification"; cell2.headers="salary"; cell3.headers="companyName"; cell4.headers="tags"; cell5.headers="location"; 
cell6.headers="experience"; cell7.headers="aboutCompany";cell8.id="hidden-element";
cell9.id="doit";

cell0.innerHTML= obj[i].title;
cell1.innerHTML= obj[i].qualification;
cell2.innerHTML= obj[i].salary;
cell3.innerHTML= obj[i].companyName;
cell4.innerHTML= obj[i].tags;
cell5.innerHTML= obj[i].location;
cell6.innerHTML= obj[i].experience;
cell7.innerHTML= obj[i].aboutCompany;
document.getElementById("doit").appendChild(btn);
document.getElementById("hidden-element").appendChild(input);

}};$(document).on('click','#apply-button',function(event){
console.log("id of current element : ");
    var formData=document.getElementById("dynamictable"); /*This is where i need to fetch the data*/
    console.log("id of current element : "+formData);
    //console.log("This is the filter : "+formData);
    event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "apply",
            //data : "skills="+skills,
            data:"jobID="+formData,
            dataType : "text",
            async: true,
            success : function(response) {

                console.log("The response : "+response);
            }
        });
    });
```

I need to access **id** of the **input** variable, when I click **apply-button** id.

Comment: Note that IDs are unique within documents, so you should not have multiple apply buttons all with the same ID of apply-button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same situation and what I ended up using was dataTables.

http://www.datatables.net/

It's pretty easy to use and there's a ton of documentation.

If you're using this you can turn the data in the table in to a json object and manipulate the data.

I would add this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation to do so.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks..this was useful.

Comment: Let me know if you need any help with it. I've been playing around with it enough that I got goos knowledge on how to configure/program around it.

Comment: Appreciate your help...I ahve one more post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35569962/datatable-1-10-4-delete-not-working .. hope you can assist me here...

Answer (score 1):

I have used datatable to access the cell columns.It was relatively very easy to use the api.Here is the code :

**JS : **

```
function createTable(obj){

var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("populate_table");
var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
table.id='dynamictable';

var header = table.createTHead();
var row = header.insertRow(0);
var cell = row.insertCell(0);
 cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
 cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
 cell3 = row.insertCell(3);
 cell4 = row.insertCell(4);
 cell5 = row.insertCell(5);
 cell6 = row.insertCell(6);
 cell7 = row.insertCell(7);
 cell8 = row.insertCell(8);

cell.innerHTML = "<b>Title</b>";
cell1.innerHTML = "<b>Qualificatoin</b>";
cell2.innerHTML = "<b>Salary</b>";
cell3.innerHTML = "<b>Company Name</b>";
cell4.innerHTML = "<b>Tags</b>";
cell5.innerHTML = "<b>Location</b>";
cell6.innerHTML = "<b>Experience</b>";
cell7.innerHTML = "<b>About Company</b>";
cell8.innerHTML = "<b>Apply Here</b>";

var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
table.appendChild(tableBody);
console.log("json length : "+obj.length);

for (var i=0; i<obj.length; i++){
/*var tr = document.createElement('TR');
tableBody.appendChild(tr);

   var td = document.createElement('TD');
   //td.width='75';
   td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Cell " + i + "," + j));
   tr.appendChild(td);*/
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
btn.appendChild(t);
btn.id='apply-button';

var input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute("id",obj.firstName);
input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
input.setAttribute("name", "jobID");
input.setAttribute("value", obj.firstName);

   var rowCount = tableBody.getElementsByTagName("tr").length;

var row1 = tableBody.insertRow(rowCount);
row1.id="x";

 var rowcell0=row1.insertCell(0);
 var rowcell1=row1.insertCell(1);
 var rowcell2=row1.insertCell(2);
 var rowcell3=row1.insertCell(3);
 var rowcell4=row1.insertCell(4);
 rowcell4.id='doit';
 var rowcell5=row1.insertCell(5);
 var rowcell6=row1.insertCell(6);
 var rowcell7=row1.insertCell(7);
 var rowcell8=row1.insertCell(8);
 var rowcell9=row1.insertCell(9);

rowcell0.innerHTML= obj[i].title;
rowcell1.innerHTML= obj[i].qualification;
rowcell2.innerHTML= obj[i].salary;
rowcell3.innerHTML=obj[i].companyName;
rowcell4.innerHTML=obj[i].tags;
rowcell5.innerHTML=obj[i].location;
rowcell6.innerHTML=obj[i].experience;
rowcell7.innerHTML=obj[i].aboutCompany;
//rowcell8.innerHTML=obj[i].firstName;
rowcell9.innerHTML=obj[i].jobID;
//document.getElementById("doit").appendChild(btn);

}myTableDiv.appendChild(table); 

data_table=$('#dynamictable').DataTable({
      "paging" : true,
      "ordering" : true,
      "info"  : false,
      "searching" : true,
      "bDestroy" : true,
      "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [ 9 ],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": false
        },{
        "targets": 8,
        "data": null,
        "defaultContent": "<button>Apply</button>"
    }
     ]
    });
    $('#dynamictable tbody').on( 'click', 'button', function () {
    var data = data_table.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
    var formData=data[9];
    console.log("The data : "+data[9]);
     $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "apply",
            data:"jobID="+formData,
            dataType : "text",
            async: true,
            success : function(response) {

                console.log("The response : "+response);
            }
        });
     });
};
```